# Applescript to turn mirroring on and select iPad

Tags: applescript, macos-monterey

I recently updated my mac to Monterey and my old applescript is not working anymore and I get this error: 'System Events got an error: Can’t get pop up button 1 of window 1 of process "System Preferences". Invalid index.'

I honestly have no idea which part should I change. Thank you in advance.

```
tell application "System Preferences"
    set current pane to pane "com.apple.preference.displays"
    activate
end tell

tell application "System Events"
    tell process "System Preferences"
        
        click pop up button 1 of window 1
        click menu item 1 of menu 1 of pop up button 1 of window 1
    end tell
end tell

tell application "System Preferences"
    delay 10
    quit
end tell
```

[image]

Comment: Well, as an immediate step you might move your cursor to the not-recognized pop-up-button and press Shift-Cmd-4 to get its coordinates (note 'em down);  next open a new script window and type: __ > tell application "System Events" to click at {[input coordinates here]}< which will display a button description in the "result" section (your button must be visible when you run the script – AND: you will NOT need the whole "string" but just the button's relevant information.)

Answer (score 0):

```
tell application "System Preferences"
    reveal anchor "displaysDisplayTab" of pane id "com.apple.preference.displays"
    activate
end tell

tell application "System Events"
    tell application process "System Preferences"
        click pop up button "Add Display" of window "Displays"
        click menu item 2 of menu 1 of pop up button "Add Display" of window "Displays"
    end tell
end tell

tell application "System Preferences"
    delay 5
    quit
end tell
```

Comment: After a lot of experiments it works for me well like this

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow, and thank you for contributing an answer. Would you kindly edit your answer to to include an explanation of your code? That will help future readers better understand what is going on, and especially those members of the community who are new to the language and struggling to understand the concepts.

Answer (score 0):

This works for me on Sonoma 14.2.1. One caveat is that it works in AppleScript, and it works on the Shortcut editor panel. However when running it straight from the shortcut widget, it isn't able to focus on the Settings page and continue. Someone who is better at AppleScripts should be able to take this to completion!

[This tutorial on YT was helpful.](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=MOdIFEU1WV8)

```
tell application "System Settings"
    activate
    reveal pane id "com.apple.Displays-Settings.extension"
    delay 2.0
end tell

tell application "System Events"
    tell window 1 of application process "System Settings"
        tell pop up button "Add" of group 1 of group 2 of splitter group 1 of group 1
            click
            delay 1.0
            keystroke "I"
            keystroke "P"
            keystroke "A"
            keystroke "D"
            keystroke return
        end tell
    end tell
end tell
```

NOTE: disable "Allow your pointer and keyboard to move between any nearby Mac or iPad". This will get rid of the duplicate 'iPad Mini' in the list.